# SqlAlchemy error: Foreign key could not find table

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

So I'm building an app and I'm trying to save new changes to my database but when I try to commit the changes in the flask using `db.session.commit()` it returns me the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'products.country_id' could not find table 'countries' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

In my models.py I have the following:

```
from app import db
from . import db

from datetime import datetime

def now():
    return datetime.now()

class Countries(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'countries'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'products_data'}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    code = db.Column(db.String(45))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Id {self.id}'

class Categories(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'products_data'}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Id {self.id}'

class Brands(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'brands'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'products_data'}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    logo = db.Column(db.String(5000))
    feed = db.Column(db.String(5000))
    feed_type = db.Column(db.String(45))
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('countries.id'))
    awinmid = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Id {self.id}'

class Products(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'products_data'}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    url = db.Column(db.Text)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('countries.id'))
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    currency = db.Column(db.String(45))
    discount_price = db.Column(db.Float)
    shipping = db.Column(db.Float)
    brand_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('brands.id'))
```

Am I doing anything wrong when associating a column in products with a foreign key? This is the first time I encounter this error so I'm really lost on what to do right now.

Comment: Have you tried `db.ForeignKey('products_data.countries.id')` ?

Comment: That worked. Thanks. If you want to write an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix I just added the schema to the `db.ForeignKey` and it worked

Example:

```
db.ForeignKey('products_data.countries.id')
```

PS:

Not my idea. Just wanted to post the answer in case someone visits the post later with the same problem.

**Gord Thompson thanks for the help!**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don t see any table `Categories`. Secondly, you copy pasted your schema from the `Products` table into your `Countries` one.

PS: By default sqlalchemy gives the tables the name of the class (lower cased). So your `__tablename__='products'` does nothing actually.

EDIT:

The problem with your code lies in how you set the `__table_args__` attribute. You assign an object to it, which by their specifications is wrong.

Take a look at the following example and modify your code accordingly

```
__table_args__ = ({'schema': 'products_data'})
```

Also for further reference, take a look at this https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html

Comment: Had it on DB but not in models but still the same error.

Comment: Delete the foreign key for the `categories` table and run it. See if it works and if it does work, then your problem is related to that table

Comment: When you created the `Countries` table did you "commit" it to your database with `flask db migrate -m 'sth'` or with a `db.create_all()` command?

Comment: You may have the model in your script but not in your .db file

Comment: I removed it and apparently its giving errors for every foreign key.

Comment: Try and leave the ids for the tables like this `id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)`; without autoincrement and unique attributes and run it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217655/discussion-between-deadsec-and-newbie99).